# How to add href around echo image in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add the permalink() or simply "href" link around the below x-image.

```
echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%" class="blog-image-border" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="'.the_permalink().'"><img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%" class="blog-image-border" /></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for. image take link of post or page in while loop.

if you want to get page/post url for image then use below code.

```
echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'"><img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%" class="blog-image-border" /></a>';
```

if you want to get current image url then use below code.

```
echo '<a href="'.esc_url_raw( $image_src[0] ).'"><img src="' . esc_url_raw( $image_src[0] )  . '" width="100%" class="blog-image-border" /></a>';
```

**This code is tested and working perfect to wrap link of image**